# How to label feature of shapefile on the color map in matlab

Tags: shapefile, matlab, colormap, matlab-mapping-toolbox

I am trying to make color map from text file data. I am using geoshow to call shapefile of the region and to set it as back ground of the color map. My shapefile is of the country. I have digitized its districts as polygons. In the attributes of the shapefile I named these districts under "NAME_1" field. I am using these codes to make a color map

```
fid = fopen('1000_2000.txt');
C = textscan(fid, '%f %f %f')
 fclose(fid);
 f = {'lat', 'long', 'temp'}
 S = cell2struct(C,f,2);
 N = 100;
 [Xi, Yi] = meshgrid(linspace(60,80,N),linspace(20,40,N));
 Ci = griddata(S.long, S.lat, S.temp, Xi, Yi);
 f = figure; set(f, 'Renderer', 'painters')
 colormap default
  h = geoshow(Yi,Xi,Ci,'DisplayType','surface');
 set(h,'ZData', zeros(size(get(h,'XData'))));
 p = geoshow('PAK_adm1.shp', 'DisplayType','polygon','FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','w');
 xlim([60.5 78.5]);
ylim([22.5 38.5]);
xlabel('Longitude');
ylabel('Latitude');
set(gca,'CLim',[0,3000])
 colorbar
```

I am getting output as

[image]

I want such kind of label features( want to show label in the attribute of shapefile with field name NAME_1)

[image]

Any idea how to correct these codes to label features on my color maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the text command to write the text on the desire latitude and longitudes..